# Show that ${1-\cos^2(x)\over \sec^2(x)-1}=1-\sin^2(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

${\sin^2(x)\over \tan^2(x)}$

I did this and then got stuck. Could someone give me some hints please?

Comment: Wait . What did you **do**? And from wher did you get this question?

Comment: Convert the $\tan x$  function to $\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}$  when in doubt always convert to the more basic $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good job at arriving at 
$${1-\cos^2(x)\over \sec^2(x)-1}= {\sin^2(x)\over \tan^2(x)}$$ 
We know that $\tan x = \dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x}.$ So....
$${\sin^2(x)\over \tan^2(x)} = \frac{\sin^2 x}{\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}}= \cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x$$

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Feel free to visit [Constructive Feedback Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback)

Answer (score 1):

For the equation: $$\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\sec^2x-1}$$

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2x$

We now get: $$\frac{\cos^2x-\cos^4x}{1-\cos^2x}$$

Separate this into two fractions: $$\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x} - \frac{\cos^4x}{\sin^2x}$$

This can then be converted to: $$\cot^2x - \cot^2x\cos^2x$$

We take $\cot^2x$ common, and get: $\cot^2x\sin^2x$

When this is multiplied, this gives us: $\cos^2x$, or rather, $1-\sin^2x$

Hence proved.

Comment: Quick formatting lesson: write `\cos, \sin, \cot, \tan...` to format $\cos, \sin, \cot, \tan...$  For example, not the difference between `$tan x$` =$ tan x$, versus, $\tan x$ = `$\tan x$`

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm not fully aware of the workings. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It takes time to learn and get up-and-running with mathjax.  Pretty much ever function/operator is preceded by a backslash:  `\ln, \det, \sin, \cos, \gcd` etc, yields $\ln, \det,\sin, \cos, \gcd$, etc.$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{1}{\sec(x)^2-1}=\frac{\cos(x)^2}{1-\cos(x)^2}$$ and from both we get $$\cos(x)^2=1-\sin(x)^2$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sec^2(x)-1}\neq \frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$

Comment: it looks good now.

Comment: yes it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\sec^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$ Putting it in our equation on R.H.S. it becomes:
  $${1-\cos^2(x)\over \sec^2(x)-1}={1-\cos^2(x)\over\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}-1}$$
   $$=\frac{(1-\cos^2)(\cos^2(x))}{1-\cos^2(x)}$$
$$=\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$$

Comment: Don't give up on our conversation in Constructive Feedback; I tried to address TheGreatDuck's interruption.  Things are great there when he's not on a big ego trip! :-)